# How to pass a 2d array through pointer in c

Tags: c++, c, pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Passing a pointer representing a 2D array to a function in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329107/passing-a-pointer-representing-a-2d-array-to-a-function-in-c)

I am trying to pass my 2-dimensional array to a function through pointer and want to modify the values.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func(int **ptr);

int main() {
    int array[2][2] = {
        {2, 5}, {3, 6}
    };

    func(array);

    printf("%d", array[0][0]);
    getch();
}

void func(int **ptr) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            ptr[i][j] = 8;
        }
    }
}
```

But the program crashes with this. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Use proper types, `void func(int (*ptr)[2])`, or pass an array of pointers.

Comment: [How do I use arrays in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4810664/1202636)

Comment: Arrays are not pointers. Pointers are not arrays. What you did wrong is not having repeated this to yourself until you stopped doubting it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It crashes because an array isn't a pointer to pointer, it will try reading array values as if they're pointers, but an array contains just the data without any pointer.
An array is all adjacent in memory, just accept a single pointer and do a cast when calling the function:

```
func((int*)array);
```

...

```
void func(int *ptr) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            ptr[i+j*2]=8;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. You made my day. But how to set the i and j if I want to store different things in an array ??

Comment: I haven't understood what you mean.

Answer (score 9):

Your array is of type `int[2][2]` ("array of 2 array of 2 int") and its name will decay to a pointer to its first element which would be of type `int(*)[2]` ("pointer to array of 2 int"). So your `func` needs to take an argument of this type:

```
void func(int (*ptr)[2]);
// equivalently:
// void func(int ptr[][2]);
```

Alternatively, you can take a reference to the array type ("reference to array of 2 array of 2 int"):

```
void func(int (&ptr)[2][2]);
```

Make sure you change both the declaration and the definition.