# Using multidimensional arrays with only one dimension specified

Tags: c++, arrays, syntax

I'm trying to use multidimensional arrays but I get an error and no matter what variation I try and I can't seem to be able to get it to work, I couldn't find any help in the documentation online either...

```
const int SIZE = 50;
double a(double A[][SIZE], int m, int n);

void main(){
    double arg[3][3] = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9 } };
    cout << a(arg[SIZE], 3, 3);//I get an error here
}
```

Why doesn't `cout << a(arg, 3, 3);` work either? `arg` in the function is pointer so why is it even needed to specify size or whatever?

The error I get is:

> Error  1   error C2664: 'double MeanMatrix(double [][50],int,int)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'double' to 'double [][50]'

Comment: Shouldn't you pass an array with the specified size as parameter? Why are you passing an array 3x3, if it's required 1 AxSIZE, where A is not required to be known

Comment: @nbro I don't understand the question but `cout << a(arg[][SIZE], 3, 3);` doesn't work either...

Comment: How can you not understand the question? You function requires a bidimensional array, with size of the second dimension as `SIZE`, which is equals to 50

Comment: @nbro How is this different from a single dimension array? btw I just learned arrays so I'm a total newbie.

Comment: With multidimensional arrays, to be declared as function parameters, the sizes of their dimensions must be known at compiled time, except for the first dimension, which is exactly what you did. Notice, on the other hand, that you have to pass a multidimensional array that respects the sizes required by the function signature...

Comment: "you have to pass a multidimensional array that respects the sizes required by the function signature" So is the only way to do this for the two dimensions is with a template like in Berry's answer? @nbro

Comment: You can simply do as his first example, what is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass it in with one dimension stipulated by the function:

```
double foo(double A[][3], int m);

foo(arg, 3);
```

Or you can both dimensions deduced by template:

```
template <size_t M, size_t N>
double foo(double (&A)[M][N]);

foo(arg);
```

But your function `a` right now is requiring one of the dimensions to be `SIZE`, which `arg` does not satisfy, and regardless you're passing in `arg[SIZE]`, which is undefined behavior since you're indexing past the end of the array and additionally is a `double[3]`, which wouldn't match the type.

Comment: What's with the downvotes here? I'll have to look up that syntax `double**` and decayed...

Comment: @kuhaku I suggest picking up a good C++ book. It's far too complicated a topic to explain in a comment.

Comment: Is there a way to pass both dimensions without using a template?

Comment: @kuhaku The only other way is kind of a hack, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5329380/2069064), part 3.

Comment: Simple answer about a template, it is a way to make a class think of stack or queue making your own, and then allowing it to use any data type even that of another class.  IE a Stack<int> or Queue<int> Stack<string> stack<put class here>.  It is a "generic" container

Comment: It's not.  Think of all those things as Containers for information, it doesn't matter what info it is, it only matters how it is stored and retrieved.

Comment: That is an absolutely horrible description of templates.

Comment: its a very simplistic description of templates