# Cannot convert 'int (*)[size]' to 'int**'

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, parameters, compiler-errors, implicit-conversion

I have a 256x256 2-dimensional array of floats that I am trying to pass into a function and g++ is giving me the error message: `Cannot convert 'int (*)[256]' to 'int**'`. How can I resolve this?

```
void haar2D(int** imgArr);

int imageArray[256][256];
haar2D(imageArray);
```

I have tried changing the function parameter to types `int[256][256]` and `int*[256]` without successs.

Comment: Have you tried changing the function parameter type to `std::vector<std::vector<int>> &imgArr` ?

Comment: I haven't worked with vectors before and wanted to use 2d arrays if possible. I also already wrote the function body using row-column (e.g. `imagearray[i][j]`) notation, can this be used with a vector?

Comment: You can refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329107/passing-a-pointer-representing-a-2d-array-to-a-function-in-c), it's C, you can use references instead, and possibly templates too, for the array sizes. Have better luck in searching next time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767166/passing-a-2d-array-to-a-c-function

Comment: Think about how a function like `void haar2D(int** imgArr);` could determine the dimensions of the array it gets passed and you'll begin to understand why the array dimensions are important.  Because a 2-dimenstional array isn't physically the same as referencing data with a pointer to a pointer.  In the latter case, additional data is needed to determine the size of the data referenced.

Comment: Go to the whiteboard and write 100 times "An array is not a pointer".

Answer (score 9):

The function parameter must be declared as the compiler says.

So declare it either like

```
void haar2D( int imgArr[256][256] );
```

or

```
void haar2D( int imgArr[][256] );
```

or like

```
void haar2D( int ( *imgArr )[256] );
```

Take into account that parameters declared like arrays are adjusted to pointers to their elements.

Or your could declare the parameter as reference to array

```
void haar2D( int ( & imgArr )[256][256] );
```

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to change the function.

```
void haar2D(int** imgArr);
```

You can try to change the imageArray.

```
int **imageArray=new int*[256];
for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
{
    imageArray[i] = new int[256];
}
```

Then

```
haar2D(imageArray);
```